# DataSet.Select and DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

How can I use .NET DataSet.Select method to search records that match a DateTime?
What format should I use to enter my dates in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method is dd MMM yyyy (ie 15 Sep 2008). This means there is no possiblity of getting it wrong for different Locals.

```
ds.select(DBDate = '15 Sep 2008')
```

You can use the DateFormat function to convert to long date format as well and this will work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for the SQL Select:

```
    public string BuildSQL()
    {
        // Format: CAST('2000-05-08 12:35:29' AS datetime)
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("CAST('");

        sb.Append(_dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        sb.Append("' AS datetime)");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an exact match you can use the [**Round-trip date/time pattern**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx). For example

```
dataTable.Select(String.Format("DateCreated='{0}'",_dateCreated.ToString("O")));
```